# Glide onLoadFailed() trigger after all image loaded after scroll down then scroll up

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I have the following view to show brand item scroll horizontally...

onLoadFail() trigger when I scroll up, but if I comment onLoadFail() every work as expect.. What happen here !?

**With onLoadFail()**

```
            // Setup product image
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(item.shopImageURL)
                    .into(holder.imgBrand)
                    .onLoadFailed(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert))
```

GIF Link: [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h8FAV-QjtqpZl9ELm1Bc7g7OdVDfZPro/view?usp=sharing)

**Without onLoadFail()**

```
            // Setup product image
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(item.shopImageURL)
                    .into(holder.imgBrand)
```

GIF Link: [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZRSx41PdAGIkNhk5upxjmmFQlLGd1FeN/view?usp=sharing)

**LoveBrandView.kt**

```
class LoveBrandView : LinearLayout {

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    private val adapter = LoveBrandAdapter()

    init {
        // Set layout orientation to vertical
        orientation = VERTICAL
        setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#262626"))
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_home_highlight_brand, this, true)

        // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
        rcvLoveBrand.adapter = adapter
        // Set layout manager to position the items
        rcvLoveBrand.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        // Snap list item after scroll on the gravity start of screen
        val snapHelperTop = GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START)
        snapHelperTop.attachToRecyclerView(rcvLoveBrand)

        adapter.setListItem(mock())
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun mock(): MutableList<ShopItem> {
        val items = mutableListOf<ShopItem>()
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/208373/files/133254608/500x300x2/calvin-klein.jpg"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://lux-store.com/image/catalog/PopularBrands/brand-logo-9.jpg"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://logoeps.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/uniqlo-logo-vector.jpg"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://logoeps.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/esprit-logo.jpg"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/b5/2c/51/b52c51f556c88216c1795f4ca433fd01--product-logo-fashion-logos.jpg"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://www.logodesignteam.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Ralph-Lauren-Logo.png"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/95/6f/1e/956f1edc1ec624cc97301e72c6d5b90e--fashion-logos-fashion-typography.jpg"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://www.logodesignteam.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Chanel_Logo.png"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://www.logodesignteam.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Paul-Smith-Logo.png"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://www.logodesignteam.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Louis-Vuitton-Logo.png"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/53/29/06/53290622f51318026dd537a2a9e7da94.jpg"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://prowly-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/PressRoom/563/cover_photo/large_slack-imgs.com.png"))
        items.add(ShopItem(shopImageURL = "https://www.logodesignteam.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Intel-Logo.png"))
        return items
    }

    inner class LoveBrandAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<LoveBrandAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

        private var items = mutableListOf<ShopItem>()

        fun setListItem(newItem: MutableList<ShopItem>) {
            items = newItem
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {

            val item = items[position]

            if (holder != null) {
                // Setup product image
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(item.shopImageURL)
                        .into(holder.imgBrand)
                        .onLoadFailed(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert))
            }
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = items.size

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_home_highlight_brand, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }

        inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val imgBrand: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBrand)
        }

    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:background="#262626"
    tools:parentTag="android.widget.LinearLayout"
    tools:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Brand We Love"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.abfabmarket.mobile.abfab.ui.view.CustomRecycleView
        android:id="@+id/rcvLoveBrand"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/listitem_home_highlight_brand" />

</merge>
```

Comment: What was your solution for this??